# Testing for difference in effect between two regressors

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, statistical-significance, t-test, regression-coefficients

So I have been given two regressors in a multivariate regression and their standard ERRORS:
Beta1 = -0.0028
Beta2 = -0.0010
SE1 = 0.0008
SE2 = 0.0007

furthermore I can assume that the test-statistic I construct is normally distributed, so the critical value for a test at the 5% level of signicance is 1.96.

I need to know whether whether these Betas have different effects on y. So I figured:

Null-hypothesis = Beta1 - Beta2 = 0
Alternative hypothesis = Beta 1 - Beta2 is not zero

I tried to calculate the t-statistic, but I'm confused. So far I've only learned how to do this if I know the standard deviations and N. But here I only know the standard error???

*edit: There are NO datasets. Beta1 is the effect of drinking of male on wage, and Beta2 is the effect of drinking of females on wage

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag (you'll have to replace 1 of the existing tags) & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Can you say more about the background of this scenario? Is this the same variable in 2 different datasets? If these are 2 different variables fit to the same dataset in a multiple regression model, eg, you don't have enough information to compute an answer.

Comment: @gung the assignment says nothing about datasets, just that we have information on wage, alcohol consumption and gender.

Comment: What class is this? Are betas 1 & 2 supposed to refer to some of those variables?

Comment: @gung It's introduction to econometrics. Beta1 refers to the effect of drinking of male on wage, and Beta2 refers to the effect of drinking of females on wage